# Customizing the alert box

Tags: html, css

```
<button type="button" onclick="alert('ex.HELLO')">PRESS ME</button>
                      -------------------------
                         need help with this
```

I want to customize the alert box that appears when I press a button, how?

Comment: You can't. If you want a custom modal you'll have to build one yourself.

Comment: The standard alert box is a browser specific implementation. Just like option selects you cannot style them. There look and feel belongs into the desktop system, not the web environment. However all js GUI libraries offer custom replacements that _do_ allow intense styling.

Comment: It is browser specific and browser doesn't allow you to change that. But you can try any UI Library like Jquery UI, Bootstrap, Materializecss for reference achieving the required behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ability to customize the styling or css of an 'alert', the default visuals for this is down to the system/browser interpretation of this.

You can however create your own Modal/Alert (how to here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp)

If your site includes Bootstrap, you can just use theirs which offers the ability to customize it with their helper classes and if needed your own CSS. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals